# Remove wishlist items when added to cart

Tags: product, cart, wishlist

I want to remove the **wishlist products** that are **added to the cart**. I've followed this link: [Keeping wishlist items](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124310/magento-2-keep-wishlist-items) for keeping the wish list items after being added to the cart.i have set my $delete to true as shown in the code below but the product isn't removed from the wishlist.

Here is my indexcontroller.php path and code

> app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/IndexController.php

```
/**
 * Add wishlist item to shopping cart and remove from wishlist
 *
 * If Product has required options - item removed from wishlist and redirect
 * to product view page with message about needed defined required options
 */

public function cartAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        return $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
    $itemId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item');

    /* @var $item Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item */
    $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($itemId);
    if (!$item->getId()) {
        return $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }
    $wishlist = $this->_getWishlist($item->getWishlistId());
    if (!$wishlist) {
        return $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    // Set qty
    $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty');
    if (is_array($qty)) {
        if (isset($qty[$itemId])) {
            $qty = $qty[$itemId];
        } else {
            $qty = 1;
        }
    }
    $qty = $this->_processLocalizedQty($qty);
    if ($qty) {
        $item->setQty($qty);
    }

    /* @var $session Mage_Wishlist_Model_Session */
    $session    = Mage::getSingleton('wishlist/session');
    $cart       = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

    $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*');

    try {
        $options = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item_option')->getCollection()
                ->addItemFilter(array($itemId));
        $item->setOptions($options->getOptionsByItem($itemId));

        $buyRequest = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->addParamsToBuyRequest(
            $this->getRequest()->getParams(),
            array('current_config' => $item->getBuyRequest())
        );

        $item->mergeBuyRequest($buyRequest);

        if ($item->addToCart($cart, true)) {
            $cart->save()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
        }


        $wishlist->save();
        Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

        if (Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getShouldRedirectToCart()) {
            $redirectUrl = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl();
        }
        Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($item->getProductId());
        $productName = Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName());
        $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', $productName);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addSuccess($message);
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item::EXCEPTION_CODE_NOT_SALABLE) {
            $session->addError($this->__('This product(s) is currently out of stock'));
        } else if ($e->getCode() == Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item::EXCEPTION_CODE_HAS_REQUIRED_OPTIONS) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/configure/', array('id' => $item->getId()));
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/configure/', array('id' => $item->getId()));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
        $session->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add item to shopping cart'));
    }

    Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();

    return $this->_redirectUrl($redirectUrl);
}
```

Here is my Item.php path and code

> app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item.php

```
 /**
 * Add or Move item product to shopping cart
 *
 * Return true if product was successful added or exception with code
 * Return false for disabled or unvisible products
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 * @param Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart
 * @param bool $delete  delete the item after successful add to cart
 * @return bool
 */
public function addToCart(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart, $delete=true)
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();

    if ($product->getStatus() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        if ($product->getStoreId() == $storeId) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!$product->isSalable()) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception(null, self::EXCEPTION_CODE_NOT_SALABLE);
    }

    $buyRequest = $this->getBuyRequest();

    $cart->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
    if (!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        $cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product)->setStoreId($storeId);
    }

    if ($delete) {
        $this->delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `addToCart()` method is declared in `app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item.php` and the second parameter is what triggers the wishlist deletion. If you set it to `false` it won't delete the item from the wishlist:

> app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item.php

```
 /**
 * Add or Move item product to shopping cart
 *
 * Return true if product was successful added or exception with code
 * Return false for disabled or unvisible products
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 * @param Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart
 * @param bool $delete  delete the item after successful add to cart
 * @return bool
 */
public function addToCart(Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart $cart, $delete=fasle)
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $storeId = $this->getStoreId();

    if ($product->getStatus() != Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        if ($product->getStoreId() == $storeId) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!$product->isSalable()) {
        throw new Mage_Core_Exception(null, self::EXCEPTION_CODE_NOT_SALABLE);
    }

    $buyRequest = $this->getBuyRequest();

    $cart->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
    if (!$product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        $cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product)->setStoreId($storeId);
    }

    if ($delete) {
        $this->delete();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your concern and answer. Yes after searching magento SE i've realised that the boolean $delete when set to false it doesn't delete the item from the wishlist and when its set to true as shown in my code it must delete the item from the wishlist but its not removed! Any idea where can i be going wrong?